# UILabel missing pixel after scroll and value update

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uilabel

So I have a paginated `UICollectionView`, and a `UILabel` on top of it for showing what page the user is currently on.

It starts off at `1`, and gets incremented or decremented in the `UIScrollViewDelegate` `didEndDecelerating` method based on a simple content offset calculation.

This works just fine, but for some reason, on the simulator for iPhone 12/13 mini, running either iOS 14 or 15, a pixel goes missing after scroll.

Attached image showcases what I mean. It goes missing for all values that are superior to 1, and then back to normal for the first page. I've tried the usual of calling `setNeedsLayout/Display` and `layoutIfNeeded` on each value update.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Best bet to get help with this is to create a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a known Apple bug with mini simulators. There's tonnes of visual tearing with the iPhone 12/13 mini simulators regardless of iOS version.

Comment: Nice. You might want to try out the upcoming Xcode 13.2 beta and see if the problem is still there.